# Принципы орфографии

Tags: фонетика

Как рано мог он лицемерить,

Таить надежду, ревновать,

Разуверять, заставить верить,

Казаться мрачным, изнывать,

Являться гордым и послушным,

Внимательным иль равнодушным!

Как томно был он молчалив,

Как пламенно красноречив,

В сердечных письмах как небрежен!

Одним дыша, одно любя,

Как он умел забыть себя!

Как взор его был быстр и нежен,

Стыдлив и дерзок, а порой

Блистал послушною слезой!

Помогите, пожауйста, найти в тексте слова, в которых написание приставок, корней, суффиксов, окончаний основано на а) фонематическом принципе; б) морфологическом принципе (по МФШ); в) на фонетическом принципе; г) на традиционном принципе; д) на дифференцирующем принципе.

Правильно ли морфологический принцип - мог, традиционный - его, рано.

Comment: правильно ли морфологический принцип - мог, традиционный --его, рано,

Comment: Вы на верном пути... Продолжайте в таком же духе.. Как сделайте, выставите результат здесь, а мы проверим. Т.к. согласно правилам форума, вопросы  не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся.

Comment: Поправка: рано - относится к морфологическому принципу: т.к.это  наречие с суффиксом о. Ср.: поздно.

Comment: морфологический - казаться, являться, рано, томно, пламенно, мог.
традиционный - в сердечных, его, небрежен, нежен, блистал.
фонетический - разуверять, 
фонематический - слезой, порой, послушною
дифференцирующий - нет слов.

Answer (score 2):

Я, честно говоря, не очень поняла вопрос, потому что у меня в голове: фонематический принцип и морфологический -одно и то же.

[Принципы русской орфографии](http://bwbooks.net/index.php?id1=4&category=lingvistika&author=karaulov-un&book=1997&page=288)

В соответствии с теорией ЛФШ, ведущий принцип русской орфографии определяют как морфологический, в соответствии с теорией МФШ - как фонемный(фонематический). Но в конечном итоге получается один результат: единообразный графический облик морфем (там, где это возможно). По теории ЛФШ это получается от стремления именно этого и достигнуть (действие сознательных морфологических аналогий при обозначении звуков слабых позиций). По теории МФШ - это результат, следствие обозначения фонемы (в том ее понимании, как это принято в МФШ).По-разному они относятся только к таким написаниям, как жена-жёны.

[Принципы русской орфографии](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook107/01/part-040.htm)

[Принципы русской орфографии](http://bibliofond.ru/view.aspx?id=652916)

Фонетические написания представляют небольшое количество разрозненных примеров.
В написании корней:
1) передача на письме исторических чередований в области корневых гласных и согласных (ср.: заря - зори, расти - рост и др.; запереть - запирать, сжечь - сжигать и т.п.);
2) написание ы вместо и в корнях, начинающихся с и, после приставок (ср. искать - подыскать и т.п.);
В написании суффиксов:
1) написание о - е после шипящих в суффиксах имен существительных, прилагательных и наречий (ср.:орешек - грешок, грошовый - грушевый, ярче - горячо и т.п.);
2) написание ы после ц в суффиксе -ын прилагательных притяжательных (ср.: Сережин - сестрицын и т.п.);
3) написание о - е после ц в суффиксах прилагательных и глаголов (ср.: ситцевый - песцовый, танцевать - вытанцовывать).
В написании окончаний:
1) написание о - е в падежных окончаниях существительных и прилагательных после шипящих и ц (ср.: кожей- межой, мужем - ужом, зайцем - яйцом и т.п.);
2) обозначение окончаний, начинающихся с гласного звука, в соответствии со слоговым характером графики (ср.: дном - днем, полом - полем и т.п.);
3) написание окончания -ой (под ударением) и -ый, -ий (без ударения) (ср.: больной, красный, синий ).
В написании приставок:
1) написание приставок с конечным з (ср.: разжать - расшить и др.);
2) написание приставки раз- с буквами о и а (ср.: распустить и роспуск);
3) написание только двух с и н при стечении трех звуков - в приставке или суффиксе (одного) и в корне (двух) (ср.: ссудный - бессудный, ванна - ванная и т.п.).

Значит,блистал-фонетическое написание - историческое чередование, основанное на фонетике(за корнем -А); МОГ- ист. чередование согласных-мог-может-мочь - тоже фонетическое написание.небрежен/смешон - зависит от ударения. Почему нежен и небрежен - традиционное , а не фонетическое?Это же после шипящих

Comment: Насчет вопроса не понял. А теперь по существу. Насчет того, что морфологический и фонематический принцип - взаимодополняющие, я уже писал. Чередующиеся гласные относятся также к традиционному принципу.Это даже есть в вашей второй  ссылке. Мог  относится и к  морфологическому. Ср.: **мог -мог**у - **мог**ли один и тот же корень. мог-может-мочь  - относится и к фонетическому и к традиционному. Все эти принципы взаимодополняющие. Все зависит от того, с какой точки зрения мы рассматриваем. **Блистал** - традиционный и фонетический.

Comment: Единственное упущение: нежен, небрежен - краткие прилагательные. Значит, выделяются суффиксы или фонемы.

Answer (score 0):

Все верно. К морфологическому также относятся " молчаливый''. Суффикс ''лив'' может быть ударным и безударным. Ср.: заботливый. Здесь произносится ослабленный гласный. Слово ''его'' может относится и к морфологическому принципу. 
Безударное окончание и ударное обозначаются одинаково: ег***о***, но: с***и***него. Во втором случае окончание безударное, хотя в обоих случаях пишется одинаково.

Comment: Ответ Людмиле. Людмила, по какой-то причине,ваш комментарий был удален, но сохранился у меня на почте. 

Слово ''слезой'' может относится как к фонематическому принципу, там и морфологическому. Эти два принципа взаимодополняющие. Ср.: слез**ой** - м**о**дой. В первом случае фонема о слышна отчетливо, во втором - нет. Здесь одна и та же фонема произносится по-разному.

Comment:  Это фонематический принцип. Ой - флексия творительного падежа ж.р., всегда пишется одинаково.С  этой точки зрения - это морфологический принцип. При фонетическом принципе звуковой состав максимально приближен к буквенному, т.е. написание соответствует произношению.  В слове ''слезой" е безударный, поэтому он не соответствует фонетическому принципу.

Comment: Удалён, потому что и сам вопрос удалён, переделан в комментарий.

Comment: Слезой/песней/колеёй - от ударения